Why I had to typecast in order to get floatvalue while solving this leetcode problem even when i had used avg() function?
SQL Server
https://leetcode.com/problems/confirmation-rate/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-sql-50
select s.user_id,round(avg(cast(case when c.action='confirmed' then 1 else 0 end as float) ),2) as confirmation_rate
from Signups s
left join Confirmations c
on s.user_id=c.user_id
group by s.user_id

ultimately the above solution worked but if you remove the type cast from same solution it starts failing and giving out rounded integers hence wrong answers
since avg function is already there i thought it should be giving float values already but why it didnt i dont understand

The AVG of an int is an int; so the average of the int values 10 and 9 is 9 (as 9.5 cannot be displayed as an int). If you don't want an int value, don't use int values, use decimal/numeric values. For example, the AVG of 10. and 9. is 9.500000.

Yep, that is a thing that surprises many who start working with SQL Server. This DBMS is very strict about what numeric type you are dealing with. When it comes to integers of type INT, SQL Server keeps thinking in integer terms, like we did when we were six years old. 5 divided by 2 is 2. 1 divided by 2 is 0.
You are right, this is not how one would expect an average function to work, and this can even lead to software errors that are very hard to detect, because the queries look correct and the results are sometimes only slightly off.
In the first paragraph I mention "integers of type INT". I am so explicit there, because there exists another integer type in SQL Server, namely DECIMAL with a scale of zero, e.g. DECIMAL(10,0). As this is a decimal type that only doesn't store any fractions, math invoked on this is the proper math that you are used to. You can decide to always use this type instead of INT in your database, but this doesn't help with literals (constants) as in your query. For these you can make it a habit to always add a decimal point and a zero then (i.e. writing 1.0 instead of 1). In your case:
SELECT
  s.user_id,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN c.action = 'confirmed' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 2) AS confirmation_rate
FROM signups s
LEFT JOIN confirmations c ON c.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY s.user_id;

Here is a small demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/_nS2_zFM

And to make things worse the leet problem hints at MySQL, that uses floating point by default.

This was correctly closed as a duplicate in the SG, and now it's closed again. I don't really see how this differs from the question it has now been closed as a duplicate of twice.
